# How to simplify deep nested promises

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

I have come across a situation where I need to break at every "else" clause in a `then()`, and this doesn't look any better than nested callbacks, this is a login process:

```
User.findOne({
    username: username
}).exec()
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return user.verifyPassAsync()
                .then(matched => {
                    if (matched) {
                        return User.getBriefProfile(username))
                            .then(emp => {
                                if (emp) {
                                    return saveToSession(emp);
                                } else {
                                    //return 
                                }})
                    } else {
                        //return ...
                    }})
        } else {
        // return false
        }
    })
```

Is there any way I can simplify this?

Comment: What exactly do those else blocks do?

Comment: @Bergi Actually OP doesn't know what to return in the `else`s, as per the comments in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, as you're not (only) nesting promises here but rather conditionals. If written with async/await (ES7), your function would look like

```
var user = await User.findOne({username}).exec();
if (user) {
    var matched = await user.verifyPassAsync();
    if (matched) {
        var emp = await User.getBriefProfile(username);
        if (emp) {
            return saveToSession(emp);
        } else {
            // return …;
        }
    } else {
        // return …;
    }
} else {
    // return …;
}
```

As you can see, the nesting is inherent to your program. It's a bit simplified already though (no nesting for `then` calls), and you can do this right now with [`Promise.coroutine`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) and ES6 generators.

Your best bet might be to `throw` an error in each `else`, and linearise the chain with that, `.catch`ing it in the end. Of course, if you are doing the same thing in each `else` block, then you could as well write

```
var user = await User.findOne({username}).exec();
if (user)
    var matched = await user.verifyPassAsync();
if (matched)
    var emp = await User.getBriefProfile(username);
if (emp) {
    return saveToSession(emp);
else
    // return …;
```

which easily translates back to `then` callbacks:

```
User.findOne({username: username}).exec()
.then(user =>
    user && user.verifyPassAsync()
).then(matched =>
    matched && User.getBriefProfile(username);
).then(emp =>
    emp ? saveToSession(emp) : …;
);
```

Comment: Don't forget the `return`s in your last example.

Comment: much better than my original one, even though my first attempt is to break early, but your example changed my mind.  another question hope you dont mind, the then() func takes a value and returns a Promise right? if in the else branch, i want to return false,   should i use "return false", or wrap it using Promise.resolve(false)? or other ways?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Done :-)

Comment: @Sawyer: right. The `then` callback does not need to return a promise, any normal value (`false`) is fine as well. It will get wrapped automatically.